# Unity 2D sprite doesn't flip

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm doing a platformer game with Unity 2D and I wanted to flip the character sprite left when the player move him left, but for some reasons it doesn't work. I tried to make this one script:

```
transform.rotation = new Vector3(0f, 180f, 0f);
```

but it didn't work. So then I wrote this:

```
transform.localScale = new Vector3(-0.35f, 0.35f, 1f); //the player's scale x and y are 0.35 by default
```

but it didn't work too. Then I found this error message in the console: **NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityEditor.Graphs.Edge.WakeUp () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Graphs/UnityEditor.Graphs/Edge.cs:114)**.

What should I do? I'm doing this game for a game jam so I need to resolve this problem quickly. Thank you.

**EDIT**: I noticed that I can flip the sprite in the editor, but that I can't do that using scripts.

Comment: I would recommend not using a Vector3 if you intend to do 2D. Using a Vector3 could cause it to spin or flip in the 3rd dimension which might look weird. Vector2 would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this thread I found](https://forum.unity.com/threads/what-is-this-big-error-im-getting.324597/), it seems like an old bug from Unity's UnityEditor.Graphs.DLL code.

Try restarting Unity completely.

This bug seems to occur only in the editor, and not after a game is built, so you should be safe.

Comment: I restarted Unity and the error message wasn't there anymore, but the sprite still not flips.

Comment: @AlexxS_ The exception is an exception from the unity editor itself, not your project. If you want to rotate the sprite so your character looks left, use Quaternions when rotating the gameObject. Instead of transform.rotation = new Vector3(0f, 180f, 0f), use transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 180f, 0f). This is going to use use an euler value (x, y, z) to set the quaternion rotation.

Comment: @JonathanMathieu I used "transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 180f, 0f)" but when the player moves left the sprite disappears, but when it moves right it reappears. What's the matter?

Comment: The information you give is not really clear. Have you switched to 3d view in the scene to check out what's happening when you go left ? Maybe it's rotating on the wrong axis, thus becoming flat on the 2d view and disappearing.

Comment: @JonathanMathieu I switched to 3D view and saw what was going on: the sprite went for some reasons behind the camera. I resolved that problem by writing another script that rotates the sprite and it worked.

Comment: Good to hear @AlexxS_!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked on any 2D Unity projects in a while but here is a piece of code I used to resolve that issue in the past. Let me know if it helps.

```
    private void FlipSprite()
        {
            bool playerHasHorizontalSpeed = Mathf.Abs(myRigidBody.velocity.x) > Mathf.Epsilon;
            if(playerHasHorizontalSpeed)
            {
                        transform.localScale = new Vector2(Mathf.Sign(myRigidBody.velocity.x), 1f);

            }
        }
```

Comment: I have to use FlipSprite() when the player press the left arrow?

Comment: Yes, try FlipSprite that looks more promising because it really should be using te Vector2 instead of Vector3 when doing 2D work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old so be sure to let me know how this works. You'll need to finish the rest of the controls, but this should work.

```
      public class SpriteFlipper : MonoBehaviour
{
   // variable to hold a reference to our SpriteRenderer component
   private SpriteRenderer mySpriteRenderer;

   // This function is called just one time by Unity the moment the component loads
   private void Awake()
   {
        // get a reference to the SpriteRenderer component on this gameObject
        mySpriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
   }

   // This function is called by Unity every frame the component is enabled
   private void Update()
   {      
        // if the A key was pressed this frame
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            // if the variable isn't empty (we have a reference to our SpriteRenderer
            if(mySpriteRenderer != null)
            {
                 // flip the sprite
                 mySpriteRenderer.flipX = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```